# Where does this question belong?

Tags: support, specific-question, stackexchange

I want to ask if I should include known programming languages on my resume.  But I do not know which site is appropriate for this.

Which StackExchange site should I ask this question on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/as-a-student-how-should-programming-language-familiarity-be-described-on-a-cv-r). [Variants](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/programming-languages-describing-on-a-resume?lq=1) are also on that site.